# Rails e Iugu: Iugu::Subscription.create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou tentando fazer a inscrição de um usuário com os dados do cartão de credito para poder fazer posteriores cobranças aos clientes. A inscrição é feita no Iugu, mas os dados do cartão de crédito não são registrados no Iugu. Estou utilizando as chamadas abaixo.

Alguém já fez esse tipo de implementação antes?

Obrigado.

```
customer = Iugu::Customer.create(email: @usuario.email, name: @usuario.nome_cartao)

Iugu::Subscription.create(plan_identifier: 'cadastro_cartao', payable_with: "credit_card", name: @usuario.nome_cartao, number: @usuario.cartao.delete(' '), verification_value: @usuario.cvv, month: @usuario.validade[0..1], year: @usuario.validade[2..6], customer_id: customer.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Dando uma olhada nas docs da IUGU, os dados do cartão de crédito do cliente não pertencem diretamente a uma assinatura. A assinatura é relacionada a um `customer`, esse usuário, possui N payment_methods, sendo que um deles, é considerado o `default_payment_method`, (no qual será cobrado as parcelas das assinaturas).

Recomendo, seguir os seguintes passos:

1. Criar o Customer e guardar no seu banco o ID que a IUGU lhe devolve [Documentação](https://dev.iugu.com/v1.0/reference#criar-cliente)
2. Criar um `payment_method` atrelado ao customer criado anteriormente, lembrando de enviar um boolean na chave `set_as_default` para o método de pagamento ser o default do customer [Documentação](https://dev.iugu.com/v1.0/reference#criar-forma-de-pagamento)
3. Finalmente, criar a assinatura [Documentação](https://dev.iugu.com/v1.0/reference#criar-assinatura)

Espero ter ajudado! Abraços.